# encrypt files with larger size using openssl FIPS complaint

Tags: linux, security, encryption, openssl

I want to encrypt files rather big size like 10MB-20MB. Ideally this is working fine if i encrypt files individually like.

```
 openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.txt -out RAW.gpg
```

Now i wanted to achieve same using private key and public keys.
Hence i have created a key pair using below commands.

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -aes256 -out private.key
openssl rsa -in private.key -out public.key -pubout
```

Now if i am trying to encrypt the file.

```
 openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -in test.txt -out text.bin -inkey public.key -pubin
```

I am seeing this error

```
Public Key operation error
80021D98EE7F0000:error:0200006E:rsa routines:ossl_rsa_padding_add_PKCS1_type_2_ex:data too large for key size:crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c:129:
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly encrypt large amounts of data using RSA, and nobody actually uses it that way. (I *think* the limit was "1⁄2 the size of the key" or something like that?)

Normally this is done by encrypting the file using a symmetric algorithm (e.g. the same AES) with a randomly-generated key, and then encrypting *only the AES key* using RSA. Such "hybrid" encryption is used in GnuPG, TLS, SSH, and everywhere else.

With the OpenSSL CLI, you can use `openssl cms` for hybrid encryption according to the PKCS#7 or S/MIME standard. (If you're doing this on a system where FIPS compliance is required, most likely you *really should* use standard formats and not invent your own encryption methods.)

Comment: The problem with the asymetric keys is, that the calculation for encryption is "expensive" (costs time and CPU power), in contrast to symmetric keys. Also encrypting one file for 2 different recipients would double the filesize. By using the "hybrid" technique only the symetric key has to be encrpted and attached twice, producing only little overhead. — So I'm quite sure, that OpenSSL is optimized to encrypt short text (the symmetric key) very fast and secure by the tradeoff that a fixed/limited buffer of space is required / no asymetric encryption of streams is possible.

Comment: If the syntax of OpenSSL is to complex, you could achieve similar results by using GnuPG's `gpg` (using the "hybrid" encryption by default).